# Epsilon delta proofs on discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Does the epsilon delta definition of a limit always hold? I was thinking about the function  $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x= 0 \\
      0 & x\neq 0 
   \end{cases}
$$
and it seems that $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$, however unless I'm mistaken this would not converge to $0$ (or even at all) via the epsilon delta definition as given $$\epsilon \geq 1, \nexists \space \delta>0 \space s.t. \space|x|<\delta \implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$$
as we have $f(0)=1$.
There's probably just something I'm missing but it's bothering me.

Comment: You are mixing up the definitions of "$f$ has a limit at $x=0$” and “$f$ is continuous at $x=0$”.

Comment: Remember:  the definition of limit excludes the point itself.  That is you only need $\delta$ to work in a punctured neighborhood of $0$ (an open set from which $0$ has been removed).

Comment: @lulu awesome thank thought it might be just don't think I was ever told that explicitly and had trouble finding information online

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#In_functions Some authors (including Bourbaki) completely agree with you: their definition of the limit at $x_0$ does not exclude $x_0$ itself, so that it is equivalent to continuity when $x_0$ belongs to the domain. This choice may make their hair stand on end to those (seemingly many more) used to excluding $x_0$, but the advantage of it is to formulate easily a general theorem about composition of limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0$ , then given $\epsilon>0$, there must be $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-0|<\delta, x \neq 0 \implies |f(x)-0|<\epsilon$

Now, for $x \neq 0$, $f(x)=0$, then for any $\delta>0$

$0<|x-0|<\delta \implies |0-0|<\epsilon \implies |f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.